# What are Python asyncio's cancellation points?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

When can an asyncio Task be canceled?  Or, more generally, when can an `asyncio` loop switch to a different Task?  It's been really hard for me to use cancellation in my asyncio programs, because I don't know when a `CancelledError` can get thrown.

I was working on a bit of code earlier, with a context manager kinda like this:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3

import asyncio

class MyContextManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.locked = False

    async def __aenter__(self):
        self.locked = True

    async def __aexit__(self, *_):
        self.locked = False

async def main():
    async with MyContextManager():
        print("Doing something that needs locking")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

What happens if the task is cancelled during `__aenter__`?  I need to make sure that `self.locked` is false whenever the `async with` section exits.  (I'm using `self.locked` as a simplification of a more complex acquire/release algorithm here, which includes some steps that are necessarily async.)

The [docs regarding `async with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#async-with) say:

> The following code:

```py
async with EXPRESSION as TARGET:
    SUITE
```

> is semantically equivalent to:

```py
manager = (EXPRESSION)
aenter = type(manager).__aenter__
aexit = type(manager).__aexit__
value = await aenter(manager)
hit_except = False
 
try:
    TARGET = value
    SUITE
except:
    hit_except = True
    if not await aexit(manager, *sys.exc_info()):
        raise finally:
    if not hit_except:
        await aexit(manager, None, None, None)
```

If I'm reading this right, this means that there's a window between when `await aenter` is called and when the `try:finally:` block is set up.  If a task is canceled at the time that `aenter` returns, then `aexit` will not be called.

Can a task be canceled on exit from an async function?  Well, let's look at [the docs for `asyncio.shield`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.shield):

> The statement:

```py
res = await shield(something())
```

> is equivalent to:

```py
res = await something()
```

> except that if the coroutine containing it is cancelled, the Task running in `something()` is not cancelled. From the point of view of `something()`, the cancellation did not happen. Although its caller is still cancelled, so the “await” expression still raises a `CancelledError`.

This seems to imply that an `await` expression can raise a `CancelledError`, even if the task is not canceled during the evaluation of the underlying expression.

As an opposing view, when I looked at the source code for `asyncio.shield`, it looks like the `CancelledError` is raised within `asyncio.shield`, rather than at the time that the `await` expression returns.

The biggest advantage of coroutines over threads is that it's much easier to reason about parallelism: synchronous operations will complete serially, and it's only when you `await` that anything can change out from under you.  I use this reasoning a lot in my code.  But it's not clear exactly when that `await` expression can change something out from under you.

Answer (score 0):

An asyncio task can only be canceled on the await, as that's the only point at which the event loop can be running instead of your code.

The event loop is given control when one of the tasks you await yields to it (this is usually done by something like awaiting a sleep, or a future). Do mind that this is not necessarily done for every `await`, so an `await` doesn't guarantee that the event loop will actually run (the simplest example would be a coro that only returns a constant).

With the python equivalent async context manager code, the only point where something can be cancelled before the try block is set up is within `__aenter__` itself, as that's the only point that may actually yield control. If something in the `__aenter__` is cancelled and propagates up as an exception, it wouldn't make sense to call the `__aexit__` either.

For shield, what the docs are saying is that on cancellation, the shield's task will be cancelled, which is shown to the caller by rising `CancelledError` on await, but the task it's wrapping will continue executing without ever being aware of the shielded cancellation.